# Laravel - Change Database Connection for a specific URL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am fairly new to using laravel framework. I have the following requirement. I have a domain - example.com, and its entire code stack is running in laravel. Lets say in the config default  database connection is - 'db1'

Now, if the url becomes - example.com/country - I want the default database connection to become - 'db2'

And also I want the base URL to be changed to example.com/country, since all the modules are going to be the same. Only the database connection is going to change here.

Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do it the following way:

Put the list of allowed countries into config file (`countries.php`) .

In `routes.php`:

```
// choosing country
$country = '';

if (in_array(Request::segment(1), Config::get('countries'))) {

    $country = Request::segment(1);
}

// making route for top level 
if ($country != '') {
    Route::any( '/', 'MainPage@index');
}

// making routes optionally prefixed by country 
Route::group(
    array('prefix' => $country,
    function () {
       // here all routes
     });
```

In `database.php` where you have defined your connection you could add another connections for example:

```
'germany' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'germany_connection',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Now in the same file (although you should probably move it somewhere else) you can do:

```
if ($country == 'germany') {
    DB::disconnect();
    Config::set('database.default','germany');
    DB::reconnect();
}
```

You can of course add many conditions here or if you have defined connection for each allowed country you can simply do:

```
if ($country != '' ) {
    DB::disconnect();
    Config::set('database.default', $country);
    DB::reconnect();
}
```

It should work however I haven't tested it

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar using environments.

Add a new rule when detecting the environment to parse the URL and change it to the new environment. Then you can add a directory for the new environment where you set up the new database, base URL, etc.

Comment: Could a brief a little more on how to do it? I am sorry, I have no idea how to use environments.

Comment: a code sample could be useful.