# How to change database name before authentication in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have multiple database. I want to change db name based on the url dynamically. How can I set particular db before authentication.

I want to change database from authentication to through out the application.
For ex.
If url is like lara.local.com/comapny1
then it will select database company1

If url is like lara.local.com/company2
then it will select database company2

Based on the selected database authentication will be done and selected database will be used for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make entry for second database in config/database.php

```
'company1' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database1'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'company2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
     ],
```

By default your queries will use the `mysql` connection to change connection to 'company1'

```
DB::connection('company1')->select($query);
```

Additionally you can set database connection for Model

```
$someModel = new MyModel;
$someModel->setConnection('company1');
```

You can use the `Request::is()` to get URI from URL

```
if(Request::is('company1')){
    //change database to company1
    Config::set("database.connections.company1.database", 'company1');
}
elseif(Request::is('company2'){
    Config::set("database.connections.company1.database", 'company2');
}
```

Comment: Its correct, but I want to change database from authentication to through out the application.
For ex.
If url is like lara.local.com/comapny1
then it will select database company1

If url is like lara.local.com/company2
then it will select database company2

Based on the selected database authentication will be done and selected database will be used for that user.

Comment: You can use the Request::is() to get the URI from URL

Comment: But db name should be dynamic
'company1' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => set db on the fly 
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    ],

Comment: You could try `Config::set("database.connections.company1.database", $dynamic_database_name);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in AppServiceProvider's boot() like this

```
public function boot()
{
  if($this->app['request']->getHost()=='test.com') {
       Config::set('database.default','mysql');
    }
  else{
    Config::set('database.default','mysql1');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing with below steps:

1 Define multiple connection into `database.php` for example:

```
'db1' => array(    
    'driver'    => 'mysql',  
    'host'      => 'localhost',  
    'database'  => 'db1_connection',  
    'username'  => 'root',  
    'password'  => '',  
    'charset'   => 'utf8',  
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',  
    'prefix'    => '',  
),
```

2 Use connection based on conditional statement(You should move this code else)

```
//Check url that contains 'MYCODE'
if ('URL Contains' == 'MYCODE') {
  DB::disconnect();
  Config::set('database.default','db1');
  DB::reconnect();
}
else {
    DB::disconnect();
  Config::set('database.default','db2');
  DB::reconnect();
}
```

It should work for you, however I haven't tested it. Reference taken from answer by [Marcin Nabialek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890952/laravel-change-database-connection-for-a-specific-url)