# Laravel 6 config()->get('database.connections.mysql') not matching DB:connection()

Tags: php, laravel, redis, multi-tenant, illuminate-container

#### Prerequisites

In my local environment I am working with multiple tenants and Redis (Auth required).
To serve the project I am using Valet.

For this case I am addressing these two connections:

```
- basic_foo (is defined in my .env)
- tenant_foo (is the one to change to during a request)
```

Until now I successfully changed the connections like so:

```
config()->set('database.connections.mysql', 
       array_merge(
        config()->get('database.connections.mysql') , 
        ['database' => 'tenant_foo']
    );
```

#### Problem

However, now I am seeing an issue with the query builder, keeping or falling back to the basic connection.

I get the expected connection results of *tenant_foo* (same for Redis) when I run

```
dd(config()->get('database.connections.mysql'));
```

I get the wrong but apparently active results of *basic_foo* when I run

```
dd(\DB::connection()); // returns Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection
```

So all in all the app will return this Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'basic_foo.table_bar' doesn't exist...
```

where it should search for

```
'tenant_foo.table_bar'
```

#### Things that did not solve the problem yet

- restarting Redis
- reinstalling Redis
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan route:clear
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan optimize
- composer dump-autoload

Simply changing the database name to *tenant_foo* like below is not enough, as the config array remains the same  of *basic_foo*.

```
\DB::connection()->setDatabaseName('tenant_foo');
```

#### Thoughts

- I want to change the config-array the of *\DB::connection()*, but I don't know another way than the config->set().
- I installed Telescope could this affect the db connection?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the missing quote `'` a real TYPO or something you added/missed out when creating the question

Comment: missed upon creating the question, fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893646/3593996 - maybe it will help

Comment: Changing config won't work since db singleton probably already exists.

Comment: Isn't there a cache you need to clear...

Comment: Thanks @MarcinNabiałek I am pulling the tenants from a database table and would like to avoid hard coding them. Otherwise I could use that way though.

Comment: Thanks @EliasSoares - do you know how to perform the way Marcin posted dynamically - without writing the tenants to a file?

Comment: @leopold What I mean you should try this: `DB::disconnect(); Config::set('database.mysql.database', 'tenant_foo'); DB::reconnect();`

Comment: Thanks @AlexBarker - as posted I think all caches are clear - also in the browser. Any caching I might have missed?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek that did it! - I (undocumented) tried the disconnect before, but did not reconnect. - Thank you so much. Would you mind adding this as an answer so I can set it as solution?

Comment: @leopold Done. You're welcome :)

Comment: @leopold `php artisan config:cache`  cache:clear does do this one.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBarker - I thought I had noted it correctly. Sorry for the confusion. Updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically change database name you should use:

```
DB::disconnect(); 
Config::set('database.mysql.database', 'tenant_foo'); 
DB::reconnect();
```

Comment: not working in my case! My laravel version is 5.6. Please help me !

Comment: No longer working, see Malki Mohamed's answer `.connections.` needs to be added now with the new config structure

Comment: @Brett Not working in Laravel 6 or in Laravel 9? This question was asked for Laravel 6 so it's normal it might not work in Laravel 9, Laravel 20 or Laravel 100

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek just letting people know it no longer works for 8+
// Make sure you've disconnected first
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.database', $account->username);
$connection = DB::connection('mysql');
// Do stuff here
$connection->disconnect();

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6.x/config/database.php - shows that there is a connections array for laravel 6, so the Malki's answer actually still stands as the correct one

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
\DB::disconnect('mysql'); 

Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'tenant_foo');

\DB::reconnect('mysql');
```